# Error register new user laravel + homestead

Tags: laravel, homestead

I'm developing a website on laravel + homestead is when I want to create a new user I have an error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `users` where `email` = test@test.fr)

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=33060
DB_DATABASE=bdd
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

I tried to restart the server, I checked the connection to the database but I still have this message ... Do you have any idea where the problem would come from?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: check your env file, it seems that you have wrong user name and password to get connected  with your SQL database

Comment: DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=33060
DB_DATABASE=bdd
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret

Comment: are you using default settings? because DB_PORT is 3306 by default, try to change this

Comment: yes its work with 3306 thank you

Comment: please upvote my answer if possible, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using default settings change DB_PORT to 3306